# Can you mod under the root?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I've been using the following fact for a long time, and as I have never seen it fail, I've started to believe it. However, I have never actually seen a proof. For $m, n, p ∈ \Bbb Z, p$ prime:

> $m ≡ n \mod p \Rightarrow \sqrt{m} ≡ \sqrt{n} \mod p$

This usually comes up when doing something like applying the quadratic formula in a finite field.

Comment: If $x^2\equiv y^2\bmod p$ with $p $ prime, then $x\equiv\pm y\bmod p$

Comment: Not sure how to write it then. Example: over $\Bbb F_5 $, we have $\sqrt{-3} = \sqrt{2}$, correct? Why?

Comment: It's not a good idea to write this. Never forget: elements of rings often have more than one square root. @JosvanNieuwman

Comment: Also, roots might or might not exist in the field considered.

Comment: In fact, $\sqrt2$ is not in $\mathbb F_5$, but in an extension

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited to "over". But the example I gave is true right? And what's wrong with Hamam's answer?

Comment: Is $p$ supposed to be prime?

Comment: Counter example for *non*primes is $17^2 \equiv 8^2 \pmod{225}$ but.... that's probably not what you wanted.

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is with the square root sign. In the real numbers, $\sqrt{a}$ is always the positive square root of a positive number $a$. The ordering allows you to single out one of the two solutions to $x^2 =a$ and call it "the" square root.

When $a \ne 0$ is complex it has two square roots, but we don't use the square root symbol to specify one of them unless $a$ is real and positive.

In a finite field $a \ne 0$ may have two square roots or none (or one if the characteristic is $2$). When there are two, neither is "the" square root. The square root symbol in the quadratic equation must be interpreted appropriately. Equal squares need not have equal square roots in your phrasing of the question.

Comment: Ok, I hear you, but how about this for a proof, it seems pretty straightforward (for $p$ prime)

$m ≡ n \mod p  ⇔  (∃ q ∈ ℤ)(m = n + pq) 
⇔ pq = m - n = (√m + √n)(√m - √n)
⇔  (√m + √n) ∈ pℤ ∨ (√m - √m) ∈ pℤ 
⇔  √m ≡ -√n \mod p ∨  ⇔  √m ≡ √n \mod p$

Comment: I've rehashed Hamam's proof in such a way that everything just happens in $\bar{\Bbb Q}$, so there the root signs shouldn't be ambiguous, right?

Comment: It depends on how you define $\sqrt{n}$.  Obviously if you have $25 \equiv 6\pmod {19}$ we don't have $5\equiv 2.4495 \pmod {19}$.  But if we define $\sqrt{6}\pmod{19}$ as the residue class, if any, $k$ were $k^2\equiv 6\pmod {19}$ then ... well.... $\sqrt{6}\equiv 5, 14$ but we don't really have any way of saying which is *the* square root.  But then the proof that $m\equiv n$ and $j^2\equiv m;k^2\equiv m$ the $j\equiv \pm k$ is perfectly valid and true.  (as $196\equiv 25 \equiv 6\pmod 19$ we do have $\sqrt{196}\equiv -\sqrt{25})$

Comment: The problem with your reworking of that proof is that factoring $m-n$ as you do may not produce integers. What if $p=7$, $m=11$ and $n=4$? The underlying problem remains: $\sqrt{n} \pmod p$ is not a well defined expression. This is what @fleablood is saying.

Comment: "This is what @fleablood is saying"  well, I am and I am not.  It makes no sense, and it's a childish habit to thing when you get  $n\equiv m\pmod p$ to think that somehow these "really" integers that we are performing "mod" on and then therefore $\sqrt{16} \mod {11} = 4\mod 11$ because $16$ is some "real' integer somewhere. So if we want to be grown-up and to talk about "the square root of $16$ mod $11$" we need to mean.  $k$ being the residue class, if it exists, so that $k^2\equiv 16\equiv 5\pmod 11$.(which includes $4$ and $7$) then if $p$ is prime half the residues have these...

Comment: Hmm.... I guess this result is kind of pointles.   If $m \equiv n\pmod p$ then $m$ and $n$ are equivalent and the *same thing* under modulo arithmetic.  So that only thing that $\sqrt{m}=k$ could mean is that $k^2 \equiv m\pmod p$ but as $k^2 \equiv m\equiv n\pmod p$ with have $\sqrt{m}$ is the *same thing* as $\sqrt{n}$....

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$$m\equiv n\mod p \iff$$

$$m-n\equiv 0 \mod p \iff$$

$$(\sqrt{m}+\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n})\equiv 0 \mod p$$

If $ p$ is prime, we will have
$$\sqrt{m}\equiv \sqrt{n} \mod p$$ Or
$$\sqrt{m}\equiv -\sqrt{n}\mod p$$

example
$$m=16; n=9 ;p=7$$

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason no-one talks about even though it is true (if $p$ is prime)

[If $a,b\in \mathbb N;$ and $a^2 = n; b^2 = m$ then if $n\equiv m \pmod p$ so $p|m^2 - n^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ so either $a-b=1$ and $a+b=p$ so $\sqrt{n}=a\equiv -b=-\sqrt m \pmod p$ or $a-b=-p$ and $a+b=-1$ and $\sqrt n = a \equiv b=\sqrt m \pmod p$]

Is that it is naive to think about $n \pmod p$ as the *integer* $n$.  If he integer $n$ happens to be a perfect square that is pretty irrelevant as the integer $m = n+kp$ *wont* be.  And we don't care at all about $n$ as an *integer*; we only care about $n$ as a *representative* of an equivalence class, so $n$ and $n+kp$ are considered to be *the exact same thing*.

Which makes the only reasonable meaning for $\sqrt n$ is that $\sqrt n\equiv a\pmod p$ if $a^2 \equiv n\pmod p$ and we have some criterion for selecting $a$ for from all the other representatives whose square are equivalent to $n$ (possibly in the lowest integer representative between $0$ and $p-1$....).

But then the observation is trivial and near meaningless.  If $m \equiv n\pmod p$ then $m$ and $n$ are the *same thing*.  So if $\sqrt{n} \equiv a$ so $a^2 \equiv n$ then... $a^2 \equiv m$ and $\sqrt{m} \equiv a$.

However...  To put it in more sophisticated terms:

> If $p$ is prime the if $a^2 \equiv b^2 \equiv n\pmod p$ then $a\equiv \pm b \pmod p$.  But only half of the residue class $1,...., p-1$ will have solutions to $x^2\equiv a\pmod p$ and for those classes there will be exactly $2$ solutions.

> If $p$ is not prime $x^2 \equiv n$ may have more than two solutions.  Or may have none at all.